# bash use output of find with grep

Tags: bash, grep, find, pipe, match

I'm trying to grep a pattern in an unknown file in a directory that has a lot of files. I'd normally execute the following code:

```
$ grep 0RY7HYLA in ./*8017*/*diag*
```

However because I'm searching for files in a very large folder of files I can't use grep directly because that operation consumes too much bandwidth. I need to use the find command in conjunction with grep. I'm struggling to pipe the output of the find command as the input to the grep command i.e.

```
find ./*8017*/*diag* -maxdepth 3 -type f -name output_log -exec egrep -l '0RY7HYLA' {} \;  | grep 0RY7HYLA
```

The above code does not work i.e. there is no output from running this code. If I only execute the code before the pipe it output the file and directory, but with the grep there is no output.

Secondly I need to put this in a conditional statement, something like:

```
if find ./*8017*/*diag* -maxdepth 3 -type f -name output_log -exec egrep -l '0RY7HYLA' {} \; ; then grep 0RY7HYLA ???????? ; fi
```

Is this doable?

Comment: What is your desired output? Are you trying to print lines that match both strings?

Comment: "The above code does not work." -> what makes you say that? Did return an unexpected result, or did not return an expected result, or maybe it displayed an error?

Comment: I've just added a better explanation to that statement.

Comment: `grep -l` outputs the filename when there is a match, which is probably being filtered out by the second grep. You probably don't want to be using a pipe here, which is why I asked what your desired output is. Show us a [mcve] containing a file with a few lines and the corresponding output.

Comment: Desired output are the lines in the matched files (from the find) that match the search pattern (the grep pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly I think that what you are trying to do could be solved with the following command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep "0RY7HYLA"
```

This will print the occurrences of "0RY7HYLA" in the files under the current directory.

Comment: Why not just use `-exec grep '0RY7HYLA' {} +` instead of involving `xargs`?

Comment: I will look it up, I don't know about either -exec flag nor {} +. Thanks for the appointment!

Answer (score 0):

I have to locate strings in a folder full of logs using bash and I do this in the following manner:

```
grep --color -r -i "string" \root\...\mostparentfoldertolookin\*
```

If you need to find multiple strings I would use the follwoing syntax:

```
egrep --color -r -i "string1|string2|string3" \root\...\mostparentfoldertolookin\*
```

The results produced in the following syntax:

```
\root\...\mostparentfoldertolookin\folderfileisin\file.log:<line the string is found on highlighting the string it's self>
```

If all you're looking for is the file that contains the string you can take the output up to the ":" as follows:

```
grep --color -r -i "string" \root\...\mostparentfoldertolookin\* | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Please comment if you require any further help, thanks.